# is it possible to use iCloud to share Pages files on a Mac amongst users

Tags: icloud, pages

I find the iCloud product to be confusing. Ideally, I'd like to be able to have a read only copy of a document pushed from one user to another user both on a mac. This would seem to be really straightforward to set up on a mac but it doesn't seem to be. Also thinking of using Dropbox but want to see if it can be done in iCloud. Any ideas on getting this to work? Or is iCloud really only for syncing amongst devices from the same user?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to share documents with other people via iCloud (at this time) would be to give them your iCloud password—not a great idea, particularly if it's also your iTunes Store ID.

Using the shared folder option of DropBox is sounder practice.

Comment: really? I don't doubt it but wasn't one of the main use cases sharing of photos from a user to other users? Maybe, we're talking different things here and I have never used iCloud before - just confirmring. thx for response.

Comment: Sharing to other users has never been part of Apple's [mission statement for iCloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/what-is.html): **Your content. On all your devices.**

Comment: thx Jaberg, I looked into it more and you are correct. I was thinking of the WWDC demo where SJ was sharing photos with other users. Not mentioned was that this would require sharing ALL information with another person. Ugh... Thx for your help on clarifying this.

Comment: Demos don't always emerge in the real world unscathed. I wouldn't be surprised to see photo sharing become a part of a future iCloud, but as of now, it's for sharing between *your* devices.

Comment: Photo sharing is already part of iCloud:  http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3276

Answer (score 1):

You can share via **iWork.com** which is currently still in beta.

However,

> As of **July 31, 2012**, you will no longer be able to access your documents on the iWork.com site or view them on the web. [[source](https://www.apple.com/iwork/iwork-dot-com/news/?cid=APP-NAUS-IWORK-090702-00004&cp=APP-IWORK-00004&sr=IWORK.COM)]

Another option is to share via E-Mail.

[image]

[picture taken from **[Keynote iOS](https://www.apple.com/ipad/from-the-app-store/apps-by-apple/keynote.html)**]

Also see:

- **[iCloud: About using iWork for iOS and iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT4942)**

Comment: Apple has [announced](http://www.apple.com/iwork/iwork-dot-com/news/?cid=APP-NAUS-IWORK-090702-00004&cp=APP-IWORK-00004&sr=IWORK.COM) that the iWork.com beta will be discontinued as of July 31. The replacement is iCloud, the *new way to share iWork documents between your devices*

Comment: @jaberg Ok, my source is of December 2nd 2011.

Comment: My source is Apple, in an announcement dated March 8, 2012. They're warning you to *get your stuff off of iWork.com because it's going to go away*. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could share documents, like you do with Box and we use to do with ME with a little soft called [CloudApp.](http://getcloudapp.com/)
For me works fine and help me to break this iCloud limitations. You really could make a link to share with other people (no need to give your iCloud password, as jaberg says.
For me it works fine.

Another option is to share your iWork docs. I mean a specific doc, without giving access to the others like we use to do @ iWork.com.
See how in this tutorial video (not mine) http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/mobile-phones/how-to-sync-iwork-with-icloud-50004968/

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! This sites mean TS a collaborative reference of all things Apple in Q&A format. For this to work, answers should keep strictly to the topic original asked about – in this case, the OP wanted to know about possibilities and limitations of iCloud, not sharing models via cloud services in a general fashion. Although your input is appreciated, it misses the point in the present case.